# Discriminator's loss stuck at value = 1 while training conditional GAN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, pytorch-lightning

I am training a conditional GAN that generates image time series (similar to video prediction). I built a conditional GAN based on [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03854-z). However, several probelms happened when I was training the cGAN.

Problems of training cGAN:

1. The discriminator's loss stucks at one.
2. It seems like the generator's loss is not effected by discriminator no matter how I adjust the hyper parameters related to the discriminator.

[Training loss of discriminator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GLwP.png)

- D_loss = (fake_D_loss + true_D_loss) / 2
- fake_D_loss = Hinge_loss(D(G(x, z)))
- true_D_loss = Hinge_loss(D(x, y))
  The margin of hinge loss = 1

[Training loss of generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXivA.png)

- D_loss = -torch.mean(D(G(x,z))
- G_loss = weighted MAE

[Gradient flow of discriminator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kuZp.png)
[Gradient flow of generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mvSu.png)

Several settings of the cGAN:

- The output layer of discriminator is linear sum.
- The discriminator is trained twice per epoch while the generator is only trained once.
- The number of neurons of the generator and discriminator are exactly the same as the paper.
- I replaced the ReLU (original setting) to LeakyReLU to avoid nan.
- I added gradient norm to avoid gradient vanishing problem.

Other hyper parameters are listed as follows:

| Hyper parameters | Paper | Mine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| number of input images | 4 | 4 |
| number of predicted images | **18** | **10** |
| batch size | 16 | 16 |
| opt_g, opt_d | Adam | Adam |
| lr_g | 5e-5 | 5e-5 |
| lr_d | 2e-4 | 2e-4 |

The loss function I use for discriminator.

```
def HingeLoss(pred, validity, margin=1.):
    if validity:
        loss = F.relu(margin - pred)
    else:
        loss = F.relu(margin + pred)
    return loss.mean()
```

The loss function for examining the validity of predicted image from generator.

```
def HingeLossG(pred):
    return -torch.mean(pred)
```

I use the trainer of pytorch_lightning to train the model. The training codes I wrote are as follows.

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx, optimizer_idx):
        x, y = batch
        x.requires_grad = True

        if self.n_sample > 1:
            pred = [self(x) for _ in range(self.n_sample)]
            pred = torch.mean(torch.stack(pred, dim=0), dim=0)
        else:
            pred = self(x)
        
        ##### TRAIN DISCRIMINATOR #####
        if optimizer_idx == 1:
            true_D_loss = self.discriminator_loss(self.discriminator(x, y), True)
            fake_D_loss = self.discriminator_loss(self.discriminator(x, pred.detach()), False)
            D_loss = (fake_D_loss + true_D_loss) / 2

            return D_loss

        ##### TRAIN GENERATOR #####
        if optimizer_idx == 0:
            G_loss = self.generator_loss(pred, y)
            GD_loss = self.generator_d_loss(self.discriminator(x, pred.detach()))
            
            train_G_loss = G_loss + GD_loss
            return train_G_loss
```

I have several guesses of why these problems may occur:

Since the original model predicts 18 frames rather than 10 frames (my version), maybe the number of neurons in the original generator is too much for my case (predicting 10 frames), leading an exceedingly powerful generator that breaks the balance of training. However, I've tried to lower the learning rate of generator to 1e-5 (original 5e-5) or increase the training times of discriminator to 3 to 5 times. It seems that the loss curve of generator didn't much changed.
[Various results of training cGAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORFmO.png)

I have also adjust the weights of generator's loss, but the same problems still occurred.

The architecture codes of this model: https://github.com/hyungting/DGMR-pytorch

Comment: Not sure this might help but from how the loss looks, it seems that the `true_D_loss` and `false_D_loss` sum to 2 all along. I don't know how you implemented the loss, however this seems to suggest that predicted labels and real ones are always opposite? 

A random guess could be that you have all the `y` with the same label due to not shuffling the data while the untrained generator only creates instances with the opposite label?

Comment: @Giovanni updated the code of loss functions. I've checked the outputs of discriminator,  the outputs randomly goes around (-0.3, 0.3) since the output layer of discriminator is linear function rather than sigmoid. Since the task of this cGAN is predicting image time series, not sure if shuffling data is suitable for this kind of task. Thanks for your comment, I check if the adjustment of dataset could help.

Comment: mmh but then can you make sense for the `true` and `false` loss to alwats sum to 2? like do you have an idea why that would be the case and is ok?

Comment: mmmh seeing the loss it could be the opposite now, if `pred` and `y` are equal now you would be approximately making the gradient equal zero and indeed the total loss doesn't move from one, have you tried and changed the `margin`?

Comment: indeed if the pred are in (-0.3, 0.3) the relu input is always greater than 0 and so `F.relu` should always be equal to the identity and therefore you would most often have a zero gradient

Comment: Anyway just an idea hope this helps a bit to figure it out

Comment: @Giovanni I've changed the margin multiple times, and each time the loss of discriminator converges to almost the exact value of margin. And it seems like the loss term D(G(z)) that contributes to generator always decrease so fast regardless of how the discriminator's loss performs. Almost like it only decreass the losses that penalize the generator and does not care the discriminator at all.

Comment: could you post the architecture code as well?

Comment: @Giovanni The codes are a bit much, I've uploaded them to GitHub. https://github.com/hyungting/DGMR-pytorch

Comment: So reading the paper, another idea for the issue might be that you generate starting from x when you call `self(x)` while instead you should be generating from some pior distribution maybe and train in this way. And so the loss should become something like `F.relu(1 + self.discriminator(self(gaussian_init))) + F.relu(1 - self.discriminator(x))` not sure about gaussian though.

Comment: @Giovanni The generation of gaussian noises is wrapped in the code of generator. The main task of the generator is to predict future 18 frames based on past 4 frames, therefore, it is necessary to feed the ```x``` into the generator. The gaussian noises is here for adding stochasticity since it is actually a precipiation nowcasting task. Thank you for spending so much time to help me! I really appreciate your dedication.

Comment: Last idea at least for today, looking at the github repo now, `ConvGRU(x, h)` has as argument `x` and `h` while when you pass the arguments to `self.gru_layerk` it takes `self.gru_layerk[t](g, xi)` shouldn't this be flipped? So that `x` acts as context but you generate from the noise?

Comment: @Giovanni It is the setting of the paper (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03854-z/figures/5), the ConvGRU takes x as hidden state and takes g as current state. Btw, I checked the gradients of discriminator's weights this morning and found out that almost every weight's gradient is close to zero, except for the bias of the output linear layer. Do you have any idea what may cause this problem? (Note: the gradients of generator looks okay, nothing odd.)

Comment: The reason for that I think is that in each step if `y` and `pred` are very similar as the generator is supposed to try to do, you are essentially summing two losses that go the opposite direction by the same amount and so the gradient is close to zero.

That is why I thought to look into how `pred` is generated, because it looks like the model is too good at it from the beginning

Comment: Ok maybe I was wrong, but can you loon in the code base, I get the feeling that what is cancelling out is `GDLoss` and `true_D_loss` aren't they the same with opposite sign?

Comment: @Giovanni There are slight difference between ```GD_loss``` and ```true_D_loss```, the former one is calculated with ```-torch.mean(D(G(x, z)))```, the latter one is calculated by ```max(0, 1-D(G(x,z)))```. I am going to take your advice (G too strong) and try to warm up the discriminator first and see if the result improves.

Comment: Another idea is if there is some sort of leakage between `x` and `y` so that `pred` gets too good too fast